# determine all peoplesoft role grants/revocations for a given period

Tags: user-roles, peoplesoft

my company is running peoplesoft 8.49 and i'm looking for a way to determine which users have either had new roles granted to them or had roles removed within the past year.

i can clearly see which users have what roles in the PSROLEUSER table, but there is no modification date on those records.  we do not have row-level auditing enabled either.

i'm looking for any suggestions on how to get a complete population of the role grants/revocations for a given period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't get that information until and unless you create a process that would maintain such information. Have a look at [this link](http://peoplesoft.wikidot.com/auditing-user-profiles), explains pretty well how Audit process needs to be developed for your requirement.

Comment: thank you, that is the kind of explicit documentation i was hoping for!